# Delphi 7: how to fill a Tlistview

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tlistview

I've a Tlistview with 3 columns, I need from Tcollection object as this follow

```
FListeDispoProduit := TListeDispoProduit.Create(TProduit);

  with (FListeDispoProduit) do
  begin
    with TProduit(Add) do
    begin
      Name := 'Produit 01';
      CIP := 'A001';
      StockQty := 3;
    end;
```

But when I try to put this object into the Tlistview only the first column (Name)is populate
I write this:

```
for i := 0 to FListeDispoProduit.Count -1 do
     Tlistview1.Items.Insert(i).Caption := TProduit(FListeDispoProduit.Items[i]).Name;
```

I need fill those 3 columns (Name,cip,StockQty ), how can I do this?

Thank you.

hope I be clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> for i := 0 to FListeDispoProduit.Count -1 do  
>    with ListView1.Items.Add() do begin
>       Caption :=  TProduit(FListeDispoProduit.Items[i]).Name;  
>       SubItems.Add(TProduit(FListeDispoProduit.Items[i]).CIP);   
>       SubItems.Add(IntToStr(TProduit(FListeDispoProduit.Items[i]).StockQty));  
>    end;
> ```

And add more columns in TListView

Comment: Thank you very much Im0rtality.

Comment: I prefer to avoid WITH blocks.  Instead, I use a var li: TListItem;  Then in the for loop, says li := ListView1.Items.Add(); li.Caption... li.SubItems.Add... etc.

Comment: I also recommend using ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate and ListView1.Items.EndUpdate to wrap loops which insert a large number of items.  It disables the ui temporarily to speed things up.

Comment: `begin` should really be on a new line. Otherwise it looks to the trained eye like only `Caption := ...` is inside the `with` statement. Also Phile Gilmore's *second* comment is **very** important.

Comment: Thank, you. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
Procedure TForm1.FillListView;
var
  i: Integer;
  ListItem: TListItem;
begin
  try
    ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
      ListView1.Clear;
      for i := 1 to 9 do
        with ListView1 do
          begin
            ListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
            Listitem.Caption := 'Caption '+IntToStr(i);
            ListItem.SubItems.Add('Subitem1 '+IntToStr(i));
            ListItem.SubItems.Add('Subitem2 '+IntToStr(i));
          end;
    finally
      ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      MessageDlg(PWideChar(E.Message), TMsgDlgType.mtError, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0);
  end;
end;
```